# Access object in codebehind from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

> C# or VB.NET are welcome.

I have an **<%#Eval("FirstName")%>** in the aspx page, I want to replace "FirstName" to **<%#Eval(employee.FirstName)%>** but "employee" object
            is instantiated in the codebehind like this:

```
Public employee As New Employee
```

- How can I call this object in the
  aspx page?
- Should I can create an "employee" in
  the aspx? if so, how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you instantiate your object as Public you should be able to call it, even from aspx page.

> <%#Eval(employee.FirstName)%>

Answer (score 3):

Try <%= Employee.FirstName %>

Comment: +1 don't need the eval. Also if the OP needs it to happen during databinding, would just <%# Employee.FirstName %>

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access something inside a databound control, use:

```
<%#Eval(employee.FirstName)%>
```

For general us in a .aspx or .ascx, use:

```
<%#Eval(employee.FirstName)%>
```